# How to set an application to be default instead of making the user choose between several ones

Tags: android, android-manifest

I developed a dial up application and I installed it to my phone. Now I want to "on click a button" in my app to set the built in dialer as the default dialing application "automatically" without giving the user to choose between my app and the default dialer application.

This code gives the user the choice,

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent("android.intent.action.DIAL",
Uri.parse("tel:" + someNumber)), 1);
```

I don't want this, I want to set the default application to be built in dialer without asking the user.

Note: Once the user is not using my app he will be given the choice, Howevre, if he clicked that button in my app .. it will set the default app automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This should open default dialer .

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:0000000000"));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: currently I'm not setting any of them as "default" so this code display the user to choices, my app and the built-in app.. I want a way to set the built-in app as a default when I'm inside my app without displaying the two choices.

Answer (score 0):

You can't force the default activity without user interaction. Why don't you just call your class directly on the button press?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, mydialer.class))
intent.putExtra("PHONENUMBER", _phoneNumber);

startActivityForResult(intent);
```